# Force webpack 2 not to use Eval in production

Tags: webpack, content-security-policy

I'm having the [csp error](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4094) because webpack is using `eval` in **one** of my bundles.

I've tried to use all the [options available](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) for source mapping and canceling devtools.
Also I've tried configuring the compression using `Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` in which you can set `sourceMap: false`. but I'm still getting the same error and I can see there's a line in my bundle:

```
t.exports=function(t){"undefined"!=typeof execScript?execScript(t):eval.call(null,t)} .
```

which is calling `eval`.

How can I force webpack not to use `eval`?
Thank you